# dplyr: ignore grouping variables for function input

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use `tidyverse` tools (instead of for loops) on some groups to be evaluated with procedures from the `mvabund` package.

Basically, for the procedure I need a dataframe with just numeric columns (species abundances) first and then grouping variables for a downstream procedure.

But if I want to do this on multiple groupings, I need to include grouping variables. However, when using `group_by` these non-numeric variables are still present and the procedure will not run.

How can I use `dplyr` to pass the numeric variables to a (mvabund) function?

If I were to just one group, the process is as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(mvabund)    
df <- data.frame(Genus.species1 = rep(c(0, 1), each = 10), 
                        Genus.species2 = rep(c(1, 0), each = 10),
                        Genus.species3 = sample(1:100,20,replace=T),
                        Genus.species4 = sample(1:100,20,replace=T),
                        GroupVar1 = rep(c("Site1", "Site2"), each=2, times=5),
                        GroupVar2 = rep(c("AA", "BB"), each = 10), 
                        GroupVar3 = rep(c("A1", "B1"), times=10))

df1 <- filter(df, GroupVar2 == "AA" & GroupVar3 == "A1") # get desired subset/group
df2 <- select(df1, -GroupVar1, -GroupVar2, -GroupVar3) # retain numeric variables

MVA.fit <- mvabund(df2) # run procedure
MVA.model <- manyglm(MVA.fit ~ df1$GroupVar1, family="negative binomial") # here I need to bring back GroupVar1 for this procedure
MVA.anova <- anova(MVA.model, nBoot=1000, test="wald", p.uni="adjusted")
MVA.anova$table[2,] # desired result
```

I have tried using `map`, `do`, `nest`, etc to no avail.

Without groupings this works

```
df.t <- as_tibble(df)
nest.df <- df.t %>% nest(-GroupVar1, -GroupVar2, -GroupVar3)
mva.tt <- nest.df %>%
      mutate(mva.tt = map(data, ~ mvabund(.x)))
```

but this next step does not

```
mva.tt %>%  mutate(MANY = map(data, ~ manyglm(.x ~ GroupVar1, family="negative binomial")))
```

Moreover, once I try to remove columns that sum to zero or include groupings, everything fails.

Is there a smart way to to this with `dplyr` and pipes? Or is a `for loop` the answer?

Edit:
Originally, I asked about this :Also, when broken into groups, the dataframe will contain columns that are all zeroes, normally I'd remove these. Can I have `dplyr` groupings that vary in the number of variables?" but the comments revealed this is not possible given my proposed set up. So I am still interested in the above.

Comment: There's a lot of questions here. *"Can I have dplyr groupings that vary in the number of variables?"* No. Tibbles, like data frames, are rectangular. The grouping is an additional attribute, the groups are not actually separate. Perhaps using `split` an working with lists of data frames would be better for you, or you can use `group_map` or `group_walk` to do stuff to each group---including filtering or selecting different columns before passing it to `mvabund`.

Comment: group_map and group_walk seem very promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copied the steps into a function. Also added group information to differentiate in the last line.

```
fun <- function(df) {
   df1 <- select(df, -GroupVar1, -GroupVar2, -GroupVar3) 
   df3 <- df1 %>% select_if(~sum((.)) > 0) 
   MVA.fit <- mvabund(df3) 
   MVA.model <- manyglm(MVA.fit ~ df$GroupVar1, family="negative binomial") 
   MVA.anova <- anova(MVA.model, nBoot=1000, test="wald", p.uni="adjusted")
   cbind(Group2 = df$GroupVar2[1], Group3 = df$GroupVar3[1], MVA.anova$table[2,])
}
```

Split the dataframe into groups and apply the function

```
library(tidyverse)
library(mvabund)   

df %>%
  group_split(GroupVar2, GroupVar3) %>%
  map_dfr(fun)

#Time elapsed: 0 hr 0 min 0 sec
#Time elapsed: 0 hr 0 min 0 sec
#Time elapsed: 0 hr 0 min 0 sec
#Time elapsed: 0 hr 0 min 0 sec
#  Group2 Group3 Res.Df Df.diff     wald Pr(>wald)
#1     AA     A1      3       1 1.028206 0.7432567
#2     AA     B1      3       1 2.979169 0.1608392
#3     BB     A1      3       1 2.330708 0.2137862
#4     BB     B1      3       1 1.952617 0.2567433
```